# jquery mobile site a gray bar at the bottom

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I'm building a mobile version of a website. I've got most of the stuffs figured out, but still at the bottom of the screen there is a 20px gray bar that I can't seem to style.

I would just like to make the gray bar white.

I've tried styling #content, #footer, header, footer, body with {background:#fff !important;}, none of them works.

If I put * {background:#fff !important;} it would work, but it also changes every other background-image CSS into white.

I'm sure there is a simpler way of doing it, any suggestion?

example: http://2ndsky.org/chatime_m/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continued from above comment of @Davor:

Try override like this.
.ui-body-c, .ui-overlay-c {
background-color: white;
background-image: none;
}

please recheck syntax of my css.

Comment: added !important behind each one and now they are gone!

Answer (score 0):

using firebug i found this is cause gray bottom part.

```
.ui-body-c, .ui-overlay-c {
    background: linear-gradient(#F9F9F9, #EEEEEE) repeat scroll 0 0 #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    color: #FF0000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```